# VS C# login 'No overload for method 'RedirectFromLoginPage'

Tags: c#, asp.net

So ive been using this site for great answers with earlier code projects for a couple of years, and finally ive created a user. But with ive came upon a problem i really cant get around in my current project in Visual Studio 2012. So, i have this small project going on, im making a website in C# which i have to make a login page (with masterpage ofc)

The Login.aspx:

```
<p>
    Brukernavn  
    <asp:TextBox ID="Brukernavn" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></p>

<p>
    Passord
    <asp:TextBox ID="Passord" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox></p>

<p>
    <asp:Button ID="LoginKnp" runat="server" Text="Logg inn" OnClick="LoginKnp_Click"/></p>

<p>
    <asp:Label ID="FeilLoginInformasjon" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Text="Feil påloggings informasjon. Prøv igjen."
                Visible="false"></asp:Label></p>
```

Then, i need to make the code behind for the LoginKnp(LoginBtn) and logging in the user, heres the code:

The Login.aspx.cs:

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
}
protected void LoginKnp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String[] users = { "brukernavn" };
    String[] passwords = { "passord" };
    for (int i = 0; i < users.Length; i++)
    {
        bool validUsername = (string.Compare(Brukernavn.Text, users[i], true) == 0);
        bool validPassword = (string.Compare(Passord.Text, passwords[i], true) == 0);

        if (validUsername && validPassword)
        {

            **`**FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Brukernavn.Text);**`**
        }

    }
    FeilLoginInformasjon.Visible = true;
}
```

I have run into a little problem here you see. 
The FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Brukernavn.Text); as i typed this in, i only get this error: 'No overload for method 'RedirectFromLoginPage' takes 1 arguments'. Ive tried to find a solution to this over a couple of days, and im still stuck at this point.

Anyone have some tips / advice / solution to why this is making such an headache?

Deeply gratified with any help on this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you want takes two parameters.

The second one is a boolean which can be set as

> "true to create a durable cookie (one that is saved across browser
>   sessions); otherwise, false. "

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: The first one is the username

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply whether you want a persistent cookie or not. It is the 2nd argument as a boolean.

Comment: Got it ! Sweets, added bool value on the end, error was gone. 

FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(Brukernavn.Text, true);

redirected the user to another page with Response.Redirect.


Many many thanks to both of you, really appreciated!